# Received error in GitLab: "The repository for this project does not exist."

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitaly

I run the `GitLab` from `docker-compose`. I had repositories with content and everything had been working as expected but now it says "The repository for this project does not exist." and I cannot get back my existing repositories and the content of them.

In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file the  `git_data_dirs` points to `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data` as default. The user/group set to `git` for `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` recursively.

**Content of `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories`:**

```
ll /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
total 84
drwxrws---  3 git git  4096 Dec 22 01:32 +gitaly/
drwxrws---  4 git git  4096 Dec 22 09:28 ./
drwx------  3 git git  4096 Aug 31  2020 ../
-rwxrwx---  1 git git    64 Dec 22 09:28 .gitaly-metadata*
-rwxrwx---  1 git git    80 Dec 22 03:15 .gitaly-metadata.locked*
drwxrws--- 16 git git  4096 Apr 19  2021 @hashed/
-rwxrwx---  1 git git 57607 Dec 22 03:15 __$$RECOVERY_README$$__.html
```

**Content of `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed`:** (It seems my Git repos are available)

```
ll /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed
total 64
drwxrws--- 16 git git 4096 Apr 19  2021 ./
drwxrws---  4 git git 4096 Dec 22 09:28 ../
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Oct 21  2020 19/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Oct 21  2020 2c/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Dec  4  2020 3f/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Oct 28  2020 4a/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Sep 20  2020 4b/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Sep 20  2020 4e/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Nov  5  2020 4f/
drwxrws---  4 git git 4096 Nov 11  2020 6b/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Oct 21  2020 79/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Dec 11  2020 85/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Aug 28  2020 d4/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Apr 19  2021 e6/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Oct 12  2020 e7/
drwxrws---  3 git git 4096 Sep 20  2020 ef/
```

The repos are even not accessible from my local PC:

```
>>> git fetch
Username for 'https://my_host.com': milan.balazs
Password for 'https://milan.balazs@my_host.com': 
remote: A repository for this project does not exist yet.
fatal: repository 'https://my_host.com/systemdevelopers/tools.git/' not found
```

I have search and tried many "solution"/work-around but I couldn't solve it.

Tried:

- `gitlab-rake cache:clear`
- `gitlab-rake gitlab:check`
- `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
- Restart Docker Service
- Restart Docker Swarm
- Restart Docker Daemon

**The given error on UI:**

[image: Error on UI]

**My `docker-compose.yml`:**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  gitlab:
    image: ${ENVIRONMENT_HOST}:5000/environment/gitlab 
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "60000:22"
    hostname: "${ENVIRONMENT_HOST}"
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://${ENVIRONMENT_HOST}'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 60000
        nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
        nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/${ENVIRONMENT_HOST}/fullchain.pem'
        nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/${ENVIRONMENT_HOST}/privkey.pem'
        gitlab_shell['custom_hooks_dir'] = '/home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks'

    volumes:
      - gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab
      - gitlab_logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./gitlab/server_hooks/:/home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks
    networks:
      - gitlab_ci_net

  gitlab-runner-1:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v13.6.0
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - gitlab_runner_config_1:/etc/gitlab-runner
    networks:
      - gitlab_ci_net
      - image_registry_net

  gitlab-runner-2:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v13.6.0
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - gitlab_runner_config_2:/etc/gitlab-runner
    networks:
      - gitlab_ci_net
      - image_registry_net

  gitlab-runner-3:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v13.6.0
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - gitlab_runner_config_3:/etc/gitlab-runner
    networks:
      - gitlab_ci_net
      - image_registry_net
volumes:
  gitlab_config: {}
  gitlab_logs: {}
  gitlab_data: {}
  gitlab_runner_config_1: {}
  gitlab_runner_config_2: {}
  gitlab_runner_config_3: {}

networks:
  gitlab_ci_net: {}
  image_registry_net: {}
```

**The `${ENVIRONMENT_HOST}:5000/environment/gitlab` `Dockerfile`:**

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-ce:13.6.3-ce.0

# Install python3 for server hooks
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3

# Copy server hooks
COPY --chown=git:git ./server_hooks /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks

# Give permission to server hooks
RUN find . -name *.py -exec chmod +x {} \
```

The `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command has been ran successfully.

**Some strange log parts:**

I don't know the following error messages from log folder are related or not but I share them, perhaps they can help in debugging. The used command to find messages `root@env:/var# grep -rnw 'log/' -e 'error'`

In my understanding the `gitaly` is not able to recognize the Git repository (I can see this message for more Git repos).

```
log/gitlab/gitaly/@4000000061c31f1028b9701c.u:437:
{
   "correlation_id":"EyMTcQIIRP9",
   "error":"rpc error: code = NotFound desc = GetRepoPath: not a git repository '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/e7/f6/e7f6c011776e8db7cd330b54174fd76f7d0216b612387a5ffcfb81e6f0919683.git'",
   "grpc.code":"NotFound",
   "grpc.meta.auth_version":"v2",
   "grpc.meta.client_name":"gitlab-web",
   "grpc.meta.deadline_type":"regular",
   "grpc.method":"FindDefaultBranchName",
   "grpc.request.deadline":"2021-12-22T12:32:41Z",
   "grpc.request.fullMethod":"/gitaly.RefService/FindDefaultBranchName",
   "grpc.request.glProjectPath":"systemdevelopers/database",
   "grpc.request.glRepository":"project-6",
   "grpc.request.repoPath":"@hashed/e7/f6/e7f6c011776e8db7cd330b54174fd76f7d0216b612387a5ffcfb81e6f0919683.git",
   "grpc.request.repoStorage":"default",
   "grpc.request.topLevelGroup":"@hashed",
   "grpc.service":"gitaly.RefService",
   "grpc.start_time":"2021-12-22T12:32:31Z",
   "grpc.time_ms":0.252,
   "level":"info",
   "msg":"finished unary call with code NotFound",
   "peer.address":"@",
   "pid":266,
   "span.kind":"server",
   "system":"grpc",
   "time":"2021-12-22T12:32:31.361Z"
}
```

Other strange message (I see more times in my logs):

```
log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/application_json.log:42:
{
   "severity":"ERROR",
   "time":"2021-12-22T12:07:41.806Z",
   "correlation_id":null,
   "message":"  \n!! RUNTIME IDENTIFICATION FAILED: Failed to identify runtime for process 52717 (bin/rails)\n  Runtime based configuration settings may not work properly.\n  If you continue to see this error, please file an issue via\n  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/new\n"
}
```

Some errors from `gitlab-workhorse`:

```
log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/@4000000061c31f28343253dc.u:11373:
{
   "command":[
      "exiftool",
      "-all=",
      "--IPTC:all",
      "--XMP-iptcExt:all",
      "-tagsFromFile",
      "@",
      "-ResolutionUnit",
      "-XResolution",
      "-YResolution",
      "-YCbCrSubSampling",
      "-YCbCrPositioning",
      "-BitsPerSample",
      "-ImageHeight",
      "-ImageWidth",
      "-ImageSize",
      "-Copyright",
      "-CopyrightNotice",
      "-Orientation",
      "-"
   ],
   "correlation_id":"ODWhqqnLNH2",
   "error":"exit status 1",
   "level":"info",
   "msg":"exiftool command failed",
   "stderr":"  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0Error: Writing of this type of file is not supported - -\n",
   "time":"2021-12-22T12:44:50Z"
}


log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/@4000000061c31f28343253dc.u:11374:
{
   "correlation_id":"ODWhqqnLNH2",
   "error":"error while removing EXIF",
   "level":"error",
   "method":"POST",
   "msg":"error",
   "time":"2021-12-22T12:44:50Z",
   "uri":"/uploads/user"
}

log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/@4000000061c343b71091c0ac.u:4:
{
   "correlation_id":"OKWMhVphvr5",
   "duration_ms":0,
   "error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: connection refused",
   "level":"error",
   "method":"GET",
   "msg":"error",
   "time":"2021-12-22T12:51:32Z",
   "uri":"/help"
}
```

**Results of GitLab environment info:**

```
root@env:/# gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info

System information
System:     
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.7.2p137
Gem Version:    3.1.4
Bundler Version:2.1.4
Rake Version:   13.0.1
Redis Version:  5.0.9
Git Version:    2.29.0
Sidekiq Version:5.2.9
Go Version: unknown

GitLab information
Version:    13.6.3
Revision:   857c6c6a6a9
Directory:  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter: PostgreSQL
DB Version: 11.9
URL:        https://my_host.com
HTTP Clone URL: https://my_host.com/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  ssh://git@my_host.com:60000/some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers: 

GitLab Shell
Version:    13.13.0
Repository storage paths:
- default:  /storage/data/gitlab/git-data/repositories
GitLab Shell path:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell
Git:        /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

**Results of GitLab application Check:**

```
root@env:/# gitlab-rake gitlab:check SANITIZE=true
Checking GitLab subtasks ...

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell: ... GitLab Shell version >= 13.13.0 ? ... OK (13.13.0)
Running /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Internal API available: OK
Redis available via internal API: OK
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Gitaly ...

Gitaly: ... default ... OK

Checking Gitaly ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Sidekiq: ... Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Incoming Email ...

Incoming Email: ... Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Incoming Email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP: ... LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab App ...

Git configured correctly? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config up to date? ... yes
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Uploads directory exists? ... yes
Uploads directory has correct permissions? ... yes
Uploads directory tmp has correct permissions? ... yes
Init script exists? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Init script up-to-date? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Projects have namespace: ... 
11/1 ... yes
5/2 ... yes
11/3 ... yes
11/4 ... yes
11/5 ... yes
11/6 ... yes
11/7 ... yes
11/8 ... yes
11/9 ... yes
11/10 ... yes
11/11 ... yes
11/12 ... yes
11/13 ... yes
11/14 ... yes
11/15 ... yes
Redis version >= 4.0.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.7.2 ? ... yes (2.7.2)
Git version >= 2.29.0 ? ... yes (2.29.0)
Git user has default SSH configuration? ... yes
Active users: ... 14
Is authorized keys file accessible? ... yes
GitLab configured to store new projects in hashed storage? ... yes
All projects are in hashed storage? ... yes

Checking GitLab App ... Finished


Checking GitLab subtasks ... Finished
```

I have already written a bug ticket for GitLab but I haven't got any feedback yet: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/349149

I would be very grateful if somebody could provide some hits how I can recover my system.

Comment: This isn't a Git issue; it's likely a GitLab one. Possibly related link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/gitaly/

Comment: Yeah, I have already checked that article but I didn't find any suggestion to solve my problem...

Comment: I've never used Gitaly or any parts of GitLab, but it looks to me like your database index is corrupted or perhaps the contents of the subdirectories of the `@hashed` directories are corrupted. The notes on those pages show that this is a complex system with a lot of legacy issues as well (NFS, clusters vs single site, etc).

Comment: If it's "just" a database index there's probably some rebuilder you can run, but I didn't see anything on that article about doing that. Presumably it is supposed to run automatically.

Comment: Probably... I have already tried many similar commands of DB Re-indexing but they didn't solve my problem. I hope somebody has some experiences about the solution. BTW, Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like you simply need to create the repo by pushing to it? `git remote add origin https://my_host.com/systemdevelopers/tools.git` --  `git commit --allow-empty -m "initial commit"` -- `git push`

Comment: Yeah, I can create an empty repo, it's not a big deal. BUT I had repos with content and these repos (content of repos) are missing now. So my question how I can get back my repos and the content of repos.

Comment: @sytech, Sorry, perhaps my question wasn't clear enough. I have just updated my question with more details.

Comment: @milanbalazs thanks for clarifying. it's strange to thing this could happen _on its own_. It sounds like maybe your local storage could have been changed somehow? Did anything change leading up to this? A reboot/upgrade? Does the directory `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/e7/f6/e7f6c011776e8db7cd330b54174fd76f7d0216b612387a5ffcfb81e6f0919683` exist and contain the contents? One thought would be if your container was redeployed/restarted and started on a different host (for example if deployed on a cluster with multiple physical hosts) where the `gitlab_data` volume does not exist

Comment: Yeah, the path exists and the GitLab and the GitLab runners are running on the same machine (Single machine system). The volumes are also not changed. I didn't perform version upgrade or similar like that. I have re-deployed the system many times but I didn't notice similar behavior before and I guess a simple re-deploy shouldn't cause this type of issue. I really don't clue what happened and why the Gitaly or GitLab doesn't recognize or read te Git repos... However, the ".git" and ".wiki.git" files are available in the folders. So strange...

Comment: Something that stands out to me is that your `gitlab:env:info` shows `/storage/data/gitlab/git-data/repositories` as the default repository storage path, which is not in your volume mappings. On my own instance (albeit running 14.x) has this shown as `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` (presumably, the default) which would otherwise be in the "gitlab_data" volume.  That may be the thing to investigate...

Comment: I saw these exact same failures. Turned out I was impacted by this ransomware, so my repositories were encrypted. I hope this didn't affect you, but here's some details: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/over-30-000-gitlab-servers-still-unpatched-against-critical-bug/

Comment: Whoops, I had posted the link to a report, but not the ransomware one. Here's the one that impacted me: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/new-cerber-ransomware-targets-confluence-and-gitlab-servers/

Comment: Probably I have been also impacted by hackers. My server provider notified me about some attack and DDOS attack. I have found some suspicious processes (150% CPU usage) and the owner of processes was the GitLab. I also have found some CVE in lower versions of GitLab. Fortunately, I had backup of my repos and I have upgraded my GitLab service to latest version and the problem has been resolved!  But I couldn't solve the root-cause just re-build my system with the latest GitLab and with my repo backups.